# Display Inherited From within Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, inheritance, permissions, acl

I am trying to see if PowerShell is able to display the "Inherited from" of a folder's permissions. The Get-ACL access commands do not appear to be able display this information. I want PowerShell to display what folder permissions are coming from when it sees a permissions is being inherited. Anyone know if this is possible?

(random internet pic)
[image]

Performed many versions of Get-ACL command. Scan the properties of the Get-ACL to see if able to identify "Inherited from" property but unable to. Expecting a command to run that will list the "Inherited from" for a principal account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Get-Acl` you should use the module `NTFSSecurity` from Raimund Andree.

After installing/importing run the following code:

```
Get-Childitem C:\ -Recurse -Directory | Get-NTFSAccess
```

And you should get a very large and granular output of all Folders, Subfolders and where its inherited from.
From there on you should be capable to filter down with
`-Path, Where-Object and select-Object` to your desired destination/folder.

Comment: Okay. Get-NTFSAccess command needs the NTFSSecurity module to run. Which will require me to perform some checks in my script to make sure the module is already present. I take it there is not a command already built into PowerShell that is able to get the Inherited from?

Comment: afaik there is no native cmdlet for that but am not entirely sure. The author of NTFSSecurity is in my usergroup and had to dig deep into the c# docs to write that module so I guess you have to use .NET classes to pbtain the inheritedfrom properly